Aggregating data, and filtering on a date, in one block of code
I am trying to aggregate sales data for the summer, for each customer. So I am summing up "sales", grouping by customer - and I'd like only date > 2020-07-01
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "customer": [1,1,2,2,3,3],
    "sales": [56,69,32,2,45,90],
    "date": ['2020-09-01','2020-08-01','2020-07-01',
             '2020-08-01','2020-02-01','2020-01-01']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# this works successfully
new_df = df.groupby("customer")["sales"].sum().reset_index()

# this gives me an error
new_df_summer = df.groupby("customer").filter(
    lambda x: x["date"] > "2020-06-01"
).groupby("customer")["sales"].sum().reset_index()

I get this error: TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool

Please provide a [mcve]. Nobody here knows what structure you data has, for example. While you're at it, also tag this with "python". As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. This is a Q&A site, so what do you want to ask? I mean, the error tells you exactly what the problem is. If you don't understand what it means, which part(s) are confusing you? For more tips, check out [ask].

You shouldn't use groupby.filter (which is to filter groups not rows).
Instead, use loc:
new_df_summer = (
    df.loc[lambda x: x['date'] > '2020-06-01']
    .groupby('customer')['sales']
    .sum()
    .reset_index()
)

Output:
   customer  sales
0         1    125
1         2     34

If you wanted to keep the groups that have at least one matching date (but still aggregate all dates!), you could have used:
df.groupby('customer').filter(
    lambda x: x['date'].gt('2020-06-01').any()
).groupby('customer')['sales'].sum().reset_index()

Output:
   customer  sales
0         1    125
1         2     34

See how group 3 is gone, and you have the total for the remaining groups.
